# winetricks quartz regsvr32 status 5

Tags: command-line, software-installation, wine, games

So I`m trying to install directx 9 for my game, but when i try to install it it gives me this:

```
~$ sh winetricks directx9
------------------------------------------------------
You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Using winetricks 20190310-next - sha256sum: 93ef93104e51331c29857e8c56430720aac185e0d99b21c6108344c27057d698 with wine-4.0 and WINEARCH=win64
Executing w_do_call directx9
Executing load_directx9 
------------------------------------------------------
You probably shouldn't be using this.  d3dx9 or, better, d3dx9_36 usually suffice.

------------------------------------------------------
The operation completed successfully
Setting Windows version to winxp
Executing wine regedit C:\windows\Temp\_directx9\set-winver.reg
Executing wine64 regedit C:\windows\Temp\_directx9\set-winver.reg
------------------------------------------------------
Running /usr/bin/wineserver -w. This will hang until all wine processes in prefix=/home/nightmare/.wine terminate
------------------------------------------------------
Executing cd /home/nightmare/.cache/winetricks/directx9
Executing wine directx_feb2010_redist.exe /t:C:\windows\Temp\_directx9
0009:fixme:advapi:DecryptFileA ("C:\\windows\\Temp\\_directx9\\", 00000000): stub
Executing w_do_call devenum
devenum already installed, skipping
Executing w_do_call quartz
Executing load_quartz 
Executing cabextract -q -d /home/nightmare/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_quartz -L -F x86_microsoft-windows-directshow-core_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_a877a1cc4c284497/quartz.dll /home/nightmare/.cache/winetricks/win7sp1/windows6.1-KB976932-X86.exe
Executing cp /home/nightmare/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_quartz/x86_microsoft-windows-directshow-core_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_a877a1cc4c284497/quartz.dll /home/nightmare/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/syswow64/quartz.dll
Executing wine regsvr32 quartz.dll
regsvr32: Successfully registered DLL 'quartz.dll'
Executing cabextract -q -d /home/nightmare/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_quartz -L -F amd64_microsoft-windows-directshow-core_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_04963d500485b5cd/quartz.dll /home/nightmare/.cache/winetricks/win7sp1/windows6.1-KB976932-X64.exe
Executing cp /home/nightmare/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_quartz/amd64_microsoft-windows-directshow-core_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_04963d500485b5cd/quartz.dll /home/nightmare/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/system32/quartz.dll
Executing wine64 regsvr32 quartz.dll
002f:err:ole:COMPOBJ_DllList_Add couldn't load in-process dll L"C:\\windows\\system32\\devenum.dll"
002f:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {4315d437-5b8c-11d0-bd3b-00a0c911ce86} could be created for context 0x3
regsvr32: Failed to register DLL 'quartz.dll'
------------------------------------------------------
Note: command wine64 regsvr32 quartz.dll returned status 5. Aborting.
```

---

and when i try to install quartz, it gives me this -->

```
:~$ sh winetricks quartz
------------------------------------------------------
You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Using winetricks 20190310-next - sha256sum: 93ef93104e51331c29857e8c56430720aac185e0d99b21c6108344c27057d698 with wine-4.0 and WINEARCH=win64
Executing w_do_call quartz
Executing load_quartz 
Executing cabextract -q -d /home/nightmare/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_quartz -L -F x86_microsoft-windows-directshow-core_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_a877a1cc4c284497/quartz.dll /home/nightmare/.cache/winetricks/win7sp1/windows6.1-KB976932-X86.exe
Executing cp /home/nightmare/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_quartz/x86_microsoft-windows-directshow-core_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_a877a1cc4c284497/quartz.dll /home/nightmare/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/syswow64/quartz.dll
Executing wine regsvr32 quartz.dll
regsvr32: Successfully registered DLL 'quartz.dll'
Executing cabextract -q -d /home/nightmare/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_quartz -L -F amd64_microsoft-windows-directshow-core_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_04963d500485b5cd/quartz.dll /home/nightmare/.cache/winetricks/win7sp1/windows6.1-KB976932-X64.exe
Executing cp /home/nightmare/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_quartz/amd64_microsoft-windows-directshow-core_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_04963d500485b5cd/quartz.dll /home/nightmare/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/system32/quartz.dll
Executing wine64 regsvr32 quartz.dll
002b:err:ole:COMPOBJ_DllList_Add couldn't load in-process dll L"C:\\windows\\system32\\devenum.dll"
002b:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {4315d437-5b8c-11d0-bd3b-00a0c911ce86} could be created for context 0x3
regsvr32: Failed to register DLL 'quartz.dll'
--------------------------------------------------
Note: command wine64 regsvr32 quartz.dll returned status 5. Aborting.
```

---

how do i fix this?

(PS: sorry for not using something called a "bin" to make this thing a bit smaller, i have no idea how

Comment: You use a "bin" by going to a site like https://hastebin.com/, pasting your logs there, and then using the site's functionality to get a link, and finally pasting the link in your post.